# How to get JSON from URL with Get Request?

Tags: android, json

i'm new to android coding, and i was wondering if you can get a JSON from a webpage with Get Request(eg. http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx/test) and get specific fields in that JSON?

And How can I Do that?

Comment: Sure. Check out the [Android Developer JSONObject](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the volley library or asynctask for connecting to a webservice and getting the JSON objects/array or string.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Look a tutorial on Volley library.  You first need to add the dependency on your module build graddle for volley then you can create a singleton class to queue your requests and you can start using volley anywhere to connect to webservers.